# Horizontal alignment of 2 figures in Latex

Tags: floats

I would like to plot two figures next to each other (a) (b).
This code however gives me
(a)
(b) vertically.

```
\begin{figure}[htp] 
\centering

\subfloat[data a]{%
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{fig_a}%
\label{fig:a}%
}

\subfloat[data b]{%
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{fig_b}%
\label{fig:b}%
}

\caption{all the data}
\end{figure}
```

How can I change that?

Answer (score 7):

Some strategic `%`s at the right places help you to get what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp] 
    \centering
    \subfloat[data a]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{fig_a}%
        \label{fig:a}%
        }%
    \hfill%
    \subfloat[data b]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{fig_b}%
        \label{fig:b}%
        }%
    \caption{all the data}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so far, but that did not work yet. Maybe it has something to do with my text being in columns because it will be a paper. my documentclass is \documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have just found that your solution works, if I would like to have the 2 graphs horizontally aligned in one of the columns. If I want it aligned over the whole 2 columns, I have to use figure* instead of figure. So the code, that works for me now is: \begin{figure*}[htp] 
    \centering
    \subfloat[data a]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{a}%
        \label{fig:a}%
        }%
    \hfill%
    \subfloat[data b]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{b}%
        \label{fig:b}%
        }%
    \caption{all the data}
\end{figure*}

Comment: @Manuel I would still accept @Habi's answer since it addresses your original question. You see now the point of requiring a MWE: with a complete document we would have been able to suggest the use of `figure*` as well.

Comment: How about telling the real “problem”: blank lines start a new paragraph which is not what the OP wants…

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help. I have just found that your solution works, if I would like to have the 2 graphs horizontally aligned in one of the columns. If I want it aligned over the whole 2 columns, I have to use figure* instead of figure. So the code, that works for me now is:

```
\begin{figure*}[htp] 
    \centering
    \subfloat[data a]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{a}%
        \label{fig:a}%
        }%
    \hfill%
    \subfloat[data b]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{b}%
        \label{fig:b}%
        }%
    \caption{all the data}
\end{figure*}
```